# Input by using gets function

Tags: c

In Below Code When I want to Enter Record of second student or >2 student .. Compiler skip Name Input and take Input for class and age .. What a problem please help me ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct Student
{

char Name[16];
char Class[16];
int age ;

};

void main()

{

struct Student a[5] ;

for(int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)
{
printf("\n Enter Name  :");
gets(a[i].Name);
printf("\n Enter Class :");
gets(a[i].Class);
printf("\n Enter Age   : ");
scanf("%d" , & a[i].age);
}

getch();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is common enough. Try this:

```
scanf("%d ", &a[i].age);
         ^ <--- This space will make scanf eat the remaining blanks
```

There are C FAQs about this:

- [Scanf interlace](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html)
- [Scanf problems](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)
- [Flushing stdin](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html)

Secondary notes:

- **[Don't use `gets`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/getsvsfgets.html)**. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: The note **don't use `gets`** is *very important*. And `gets` is deprecated, and removed (or deprecated) in recent C or Posix standards

Comment: how to get input by fgets in above case ?

Comment: @MUHAMMADFaysal Look in the manual. If I just tell you it won't teach you anything.

Answer (score 3):

First off, never use `gets`.  There is no way to tell it how big your buffer is, so it will cheerfully write input past the end and make the program blow up.  This used to be the number one cause of remotely exploitable security holes in network servers.

Second off, *never use any of the `*scanf` functions either*, because:

1. Some `scanf` format strings are just as unsafe as `gets`, notably `%s` with no size modifiers.
2. Numeric overflow inside `scanf` provokes undefined behavior, which means your program may crash simply because someone typed a number that was too big.
3. It is extremely difficult to write a *robust* input parser using `scanf`, because if it fails, it does not tell you precisely where the problem characters were.

For a simple task like this one, you should use [`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) (or, better, [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) if you have it) and convert the age to an integer with [`strtoul`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul).  (Age cannot be negative, so you want the unsigned version.  Don't use `atoi` and friends - just like `*scanf`, they don't give you enough information about invalid input.)

For more complicated tasks, you should reach for [`lex`](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) and [`yacc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/).

Answer (score 1):

It's the `scanf`. When you press `ENTER` after it, the newline completes the next call to `gets`.

To fix this, you can add a `getchar` at the end of the loop, after the `scanf`,  which will consume the newline.

```
for(int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)
{
    printf("\n Enter Name  :");
    gets(a[i].Name);
    printf("\n Enter Class :");
    gets(a[i].Class);
    printf("\n Enter Age   : ");
    scanf("%d" , & a[i].age);
    getchar();
}
```