# Print pointer character as hexadecimal

Tags: c, string, pointers, character

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char *c="";
    printf("Input: ");
    scanf_s("%c", c);
    printf("%x", *c);
}
```

I want to input a few characters, and then output the entire string as a hexadecimal value. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a *buffer*, not a string constant, to read into.  Also, never use any of the `*scanf` functions, and never use any of the `*_s` functions either.

The correct way to write your program is something like this:

```
int
main(void)
{
  char line[80];
  char *p;

  fputs("Input: ", stdout);
  fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);

  for (p = line; *p; p++)
    printf("%02x", *p);

  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```

... but I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "output the entire string as a hexadecimal value" so this may not be *quite* what you want.

Comment: Scanning a single character at a time might not be the best way to do it, but it's not invalid either.

Comment: this worked, but is there anyway to do this all at once? also why is scanf bad practice?

Comment: Sorry, do what all at once?  I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Regarding `scanf`, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134208/input-by-using-gets-function/9134440#9134440

Answer (score 1):

Your entire code is wrong. It should look something like this:

```
printf("Input: ");

char c = fgetc(stdin);
printf("%X", c);
```

Comment: Your code is just as wrong as the original, in that it stops after a single character.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop to read multiple characters and output each of them. You probably want to change the format to `%02x` to make sure each character outputs 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;              /* Use unsigned to avoid sign extension */
    while ((i = getchar()) != EOF)   /* Process everything until EOF         */
    {
        printf("%02X ", i);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```