# Scanf in MIPS assembler language?

Tags: c, mips

I understand the basic functions of MIPS, but I do not understand how to declare variables and especially do not understand how to write the equivalent of scanf()/printf() in MIPS (can't find anything about them online when I search). Here is the code I am trying to translate for now:

```
#include <stdio>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{ 
 unsigned long int n; 
 scanf("%d", &n); 
 printf("%lu",fact(n)); 
}
```

Any guidance?

Comment: `#include <stdio>` ? It's not MIPS assembler, it's just a C, by the way.

Comment: Yes sorry, that is meant to be at the top

Comment: You could try compiling it for mips and looking at the assembly.

Comment: `scanf` itself is a pretty long routine, and uses lots of tables and subroutines. It even [has its own poor man's regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873542/use-scanf-with-regular-expressions). Writing the same thing in MIPS is an exercise in futility. Since you only want a *number*, try lower level one-character input in a loop.

Comment: I'm reading about syscall atm

Comment: Are you using a simulator? `spim`? `MARS`?

Comment: Minor: should be `scanf("%lu", &n);`

Comment: I downloaded spim but don't really know how to write lines of code.

Comment: If you don't know how to write lines of code, then I think "I understand the basic functions of MIPS" is not an accurate statement.

Comment: I mean do I need to put it in notepad and like open the file? I don't see where i can click 'new file'

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the MIPS simulator system calls (syscalls). Here are the [SPIM syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPIM) and the [MARS syscalls](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html).

syscall 7 is read double, which is roughly equivalent to `scanf("%d", &n)`

syscall 1 is print integer, which is equivalent to `printf("%u",n)`

```
li   $v0, 1    # service 1 is print integer
move $a0, $t0  # move register to be printed into argument register $a0
syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably do *not* want to re-implement scanf in assembly.  It is much more productive to implement in C or other high-level language.  Even better would be to grab an open source implementation, like in glibc.

Here is the source code for scanf() in glibc:  http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.19/scanf_8c_source.html

Here is a GPL-like implementation:  http://mirror.fsf.org/pmon2000/3.x/src/lib/libc/scanf.c