# scanf buffering with tabs and newlines

Tags: c

I'm confused about the behavior of scanf when handling whitespace.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
int main()
{
  int val;
  int c;

  scanf("%d\t", &val);

  c = getchar();

  if(c == EOF)
    printf("eof");
  else if(c == '\t')
    printf("tab");
  else if(c == '\n')
    printf("newline");
}
```

And here's the input that I'm passing it:

```
1234<tab><newline>
```

I would expect this to print "newline", since the scanf is only looking for tabs, and supposedly scanf leaves whitespace in the buffer by default. Instead, it prints "eof". The `%d\t` seems to be swallowing the newline.

Am I missing something about how scanf works?

Note that if I change it to the following, it correctly prints "newline":

```
int main()
{
  int val;
  int c;

  scanf("%d", &val);

  getchar(); /* note this extra getchar */

  c = getchar();

  if(c == EOF)
    printf("eof");
  else if(c == '\t')
    printf("tab");
  else if(c == '\n')
    printf("newline");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*Any* amount of whitespace in the pattern (`\t`) matches *any* amount of whitespace in the input (`\t\n`).

From the man page:

```
White space (such as blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the format string match any amount of white space, including none, in the input.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have encountered one of the more notorious reasons why [`*scanf` should never be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134208/input-by-using-gets-function/9134440#9134440): the confusing whitespace handling.  Your `'\t'` doesn't just match a single tab, it matches *any amount of any kind of whitespace*, including the newline!

The best way to do this sort of thing, assuming you have [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline), looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *line = 0;
    char *p;
    long val;

    (void) getline(&line, 0, stdin);

    val = strtol(line, &p, 10);
    if (*p == '\0')
        puts("eof (no tab)");
    else {
        if (*p != '\t')
            printf("no tab, %c instead\n", *p);
        p++;
        if (*p == '\0')
            puts("eof");
        else if (*p == '\t')
            puts("tab");
        else if (*p == '\n')
            puts("newline");
    }

    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't have `getline`, [`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) is often good enough.  (WARNING: do not confuse `fgets` with `gets`.  `gets` is dangerous and should never be used, but `fgets` is only inconvenient if you want your program to be robust in the face of extra-long input lines.)

Answer (score 0):

"I'm confused about the behavior of scanf when handling whitespace." is a universal claim!

If there is any whitespace in the format string, it will consume all whitespace, so "\t" matches any string of whitespace.